# debug for HTML/CSS in Codecademy

Tags: html, css

Here's where I'm stuck: I'm having trouble with an *nth-child* statement. Here's the HTML and the CSS. I'm in "CSS Selectors 23/23" lesson of Codecademy and can't advance until I figure this out:

```
HTML:
<body>
<h3 class="fancy">Blah Blah Blah </h>
 <p class="fancy">Blabbidy Blah</p>
 <p id="serious">Bling Bling</p>
 <p> problem child</p>
</body>

CSS:
body :nth-child(4) {
font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: What is `nth-child`?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the explanation given in w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Could be the `/h>` instead of `/h3>` is causing the element not to be counted.

Comment: Hi William - yes it was the /h3 missing the 3.  A rookie mistake.  So grateful for your help and that of others here.  Incredibly useful. I can't wait until I know a thing or two and can give back.  Sincere best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

The `body:nth-child(4)` selector [selects the fourth sibling of body](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) - which there is none of. You want to be selecting the `p` element instead. Notice also that there shouldn't be a space between the element-selector and the pseudo-selector. Finally, your `h3` element isn't closed correctly.

Maybe somehting like this is what you were after:

```css
p:nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 class="fancy">Blah Blah Blah </h3>
  <p class="fancy">Blabbidy Blah</p>
  <p id="serious">Bling Bling</p>
  <p>problem child</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Lipo.  I think  4th child counts h3 as first child and "problem child as 4th.  Turns out the real issue was the /h3 not having a 3. **Thanks so much for your help.  I really appreciate it.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be selecting the p element

```css
p:nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 class="fancy">Blah Blah Blah </h3>
 <p class="fancy">Blabbidy Blah</p>
 <p id="serious">Bling Bling</p>
 <p> problem child</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you AnnieMac for helping a rookie.  I really appreciate it.  Problem solved (now's where you flip your cape and fly off into the sunset).  Best wishes and thanks again.

Comment: No worries! We all have to start somewhere. Happy coding! *flips cape & flies away*

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the failure to close the `h3` tag.

Simply adjust/correct that and the **existing** selector works just fine.

```css
body :nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="fancy">Blah Blah Blah </h3>
<p class="fancy">Blabbidy Blah</p>
<p id="serious">Bling Bling</p>
<p>problem child</p>
```

Failure to close the tag causes the browser to do it for you **after** the rest of the elements as you can see in this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mnrsfrxL/). Accordingly there is no 4th child of the body and the selector fails.

Comment: You got it.  Such a basic mistake and I spent hours (not) figuring it out.  Truly appreciate your help.  Newbies like me couldn't get off the ground without patience of folks like you.  Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to accept this as the answer or just upvote if it was helpful.